# shinyFiles defining a web directory as the root

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a simple shiny app using shineFiles that allows users to select a file for download from a directory on the web.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage( 

  shinyFilesButton('files', label='File select', title='Please select a file', multiple=FALSE)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  shinyFileChoose(input, 'files', 
                  roots = (root = c('http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/mirrors/ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/blast/db/')), 
                  filetypes=c('', 'txt' , '.gz' , '.md5'))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui , server = server)
```

However, I am getting the below error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6772
Warning: Error in fileGet: Roots must be a named vector or a function returning one
Stack trace (innermost first):
    60: fileGet
    59: do.call
    58: observerFunc
     1: runApp
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

I need help in defining the directory as: http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/mirrors/ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/blast/db/

Comment: There is a typo, it is not "roots" but "root": `root = c(root = 'http://mirrors.vbi.vt.edu/mirrors/ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/blast/db/'), ` This shows the pop up box to select file, but it doesn't show any files...

Comment: Thank you. I understand the error message now

Comment: Did you solve the problem, what was the issue? Was it just a typo?